# SQL: Sublime-->PHPMyAdmin formatting error?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, sublimetext3

this is probably a very rookie mistake (I`m totally new to SQL), but I hope you can help me. I have written some SQL code in Sublime Text. When trying to paste it into PHPMyadmin (web) I get some error messages. I think the code is right, so it seems like something happened to the formatting. Does anybody have any clues what I might have done wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: error message 1]

[image: error message 2]

Comment: Does the same code work just fine if you manually type it instead of copying and pasting it from Sublime? Your error looks to me like you might be using a dialect of SQL that the database you're using doesn't understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it works fine if I type the exact same code directly in PHPMyAdmin. Seems like something happens to the text-formatting when pasting it from Sublime to PHPMyAdmin

Comment: In that case I'd double check what encoding you have Sublime set to.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot:-) Should I encode with or without BOM by the way?

Comment: My gut reaction would be no BOM (just because they seem to cause various problems), but I don't know what the tools you're using prefer. In which case, whichever one seems to work best is probably where you want to be. :)